# JSON support was not enabled-Modsecurity

Tags: mod-security, yajl

1) I have compiled modsecurity using YAJL using --with-yajl but in the config log I see that the yajl library is not picked and in the modsecurity log I get 
"JSON support was not enabled"

Comment: Even after using --with-yajl.. in the make file i see blank values for the following                                                                                   YAJL_CFLAGS = 
YAJL_LDADD = 
YAJL_LDFLAGS = 
YAJL_LIBS =

Answer (score 4):

I initially had mod_security working with PHP 5.5 and Apache 2.4, with Ubuntu 12.04, but after enabling JSON request inspection I got the same error as you reported.

To fix it, I had to make yajl, re-compile mod_security with the yajl configure option, and then ensure that Apache was using the updated mod_security, and restart Apache.

mod_security was then able to successfully parse json request body and not output the error any longer.

---

I went to http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/ and found the download package for [yajl-2.1.0](http://github.com/lloyd/yajl/tarball/2.1.0), and then referred to https://gist.github.com/rpfilomeno/1140359f4bd360137a98.

For example:

`tar -xvzf lloyd-yajl-2.1.0-0-ga0ecdde.tar.gz
cd lloyd-yajl-66cb08c/
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig`

That should install yajl. Then `cd` to the folder with the mod_security files, and run

`cd ../modsecurity-2.9.1/
sudo ./configure --with-yajl="/usr/local/lib /usr/local"
sudo make
sudo make install`

I then configured it to run with Apache 2.4, and have been able to parse requests with a JSON body.

*Note that when making yajl, if there is an error relating to cmake not being installed, run the following `sudo apt-get install cmake`, and then try making it again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.log if it has following

```
checking for libyajl config script... no
checking for yajl install... no
configure: optional yajl library not found
```

Then create a link to yajl.pc as

```
# ln -s /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/yajl.pc /usr/share/pkgconfig/yajl.pc
```

In my case file yajl.pc was in /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/ location. If you cannot find it there try " find / -name yajl.pc " to locate it.

Hope this helps you.